# How to get realistic glass within glass look?

Tags: materials

I've modeled a Klein bottle, but the glass inside the glass never shows up properly.

[image: Klein Try]

As in, the glass 'weld' part on the inside of the bottle (where the tube meets the base) never shows up. I've tried all sorts of combinations of nodes for the material (Glass, transparent, translucent, diffuse, fresnel...) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your problem is likely normals, without a proper look at your topology it is impossible to say, but it looks like you mesh is either non-manifold, or at least has inconsistent normals. Please edit your question and show a topology screenshot of your mesh with visible wireframe.

Comment: Questions: does the glass have any thickness? What does your current node setup look like? Are the normals consistent? Please use the [edit] link to add more information on your question. It's hard to guess what you have with the current information.

Comment: Please upload your .blend file [here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). It doesn't look like a material issue. One guess is that the mesh isn't solid, which it needs to be. Also make sure that the mesh isn't connected to itself at the intersection of body and neck.

Comment: I realised the things about the normals (after all Klein Bottle is inorientable surface), so I split the Klein bottle into three different sections, each of which is orientable (you can kind of see the breaks in the sections on the handle of the bottle) So it's still just a problem with the material of the glass... I can make the part of the bottle 'inside' to be colored a lot darker so it shows up, but it looks really unnatural.

Comment: Try looking at the bottle from underneath. I may be wrong but it looks like the materials. The fact that it's different sections likely has something to do with it. Also, have you used / tried the solidify modifier?

Comment: Have you tried looking from underneath? I believe the material is fine and the bottle looks fine but it's hard to tell. The fact the bottle is in different sections also probably has something to do with it. Have you tried using the solidify modifier on all three sections?

Comment: maybe if you add a thickness modifier?